# convert docx to pdf in java

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(docPath));
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);

        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("This is new Text in this document.");

        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

        document.close();
        out.close();
```

fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:71)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:39)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:46)

```
fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid integer value: 14.399999999999999
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:71)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:39)
    at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:46)
    at com.snapsign.backend.utils.DocumentConversion.fileConvert(DocumentConversion.java:76)
    at com.snapsign.backend.utils.DocumentConversion.fileConversation(DocumentConversion.java:127)
    at com.snapsign.backend.utils.amazon.UploadFile.uploadAdminDocument(UploadFile.java:47)
    at com.snapsign.backend.controller.HtmlConversationController.convertFile(HtmlConversationController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.snapsign.backend.config.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid integer value: 14.399999999999999
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase$ValueOutOfRangeValidationContext.invalid(XmlObjectBase.java:328)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolder.lex(JavaIntegerHolder.java:50)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolderEx.set_text(JavaIntegerHolderEx.java:40)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.update_from_wscanon_text(XmlObjectBase.java:1180)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_dated(XmlObjectBase.java:1319)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolder.getBigIntegerValue(JavaIntegerHolder.java:58)
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTSpacingImpl.getLine(Unknown Source)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.paragraph.ParagraphLineSpacingValueProvider.getValue(ParagraphLineSpacingValueProvider.java:80)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.paragraph.ParagraphLineSpacingValueProvider.getValue(ParagraphLineSpacingValueProvider.java:49)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.paragraph.AbstractSpacingParagraphValueProvider.getValue(AbstractSpacingParagraphValueProvider.java:48)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.paragraph.AbstractParagraphValueProvider.getValueFromElement(AbstractParagraphValueProvider.java:74)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.paragraph.AbstractParagraphValueProvider.getValueFromElement(AbstractParagraphValueProvider.java:42)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.AbstractValueProvider.internalGetValue(AbstractValueProvider.java:51)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.AbstractValueProvider.getValue(AbstractValueProvider.java:42)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.getParagraphSpacing(XWPFStylesDocument.java:524)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.startVisitParagraph(PdfMapper.java:304)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.startVisitParagraph(PdfMapper.java:112)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitParagraph(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:409)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitBodyElements(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:263)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.start(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:215)
        at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:57)
        ... 91 more

```
using maven:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This works for me without problems. Can you please show the full stacktrace? Maybe there is something problematic in the `*.docx` file behind `docPath`.

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace exactly as you get it? As it is now, it is totally unclear.

Answer (score 2):

According to the stack trace

```
...
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid integer value: 14.399999999999999 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase$ValueOutOfRangeValidationContext.invalid(XmlObjectBase.java:328) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolder.lex(JavaIntegerHolder.java:50) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolderEx.set_text(JavaIntegerHolderEx.java:40) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.update_from_wscanon_text(XmlObjectBase.java:1180) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_dated(XmlObjectBase.java:1319) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaIntegerHolder.getBigIntegerValue(JavaIntegerHolder.java:58) 
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTSpacingImpl.getLine(Unknown Source)
...
```

the internally `XML` of the `*.docx` file is corrupt. There is a paragraph line spacing set `w:line="14.399999999999999"`. The `XML` looks like:

```
...
<w:p>
 <w:pPr>
  <w:spacing ... w:line="14.399999999999999" w:lineRule="exact"/>
...
```

But `w:line` attribute must only contain integer values. It must be given in 1/10 half `pt`. So line spacing of `14pt` would be `w:line="280"`.

The `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTSpacingImpl.getLine` tries getting a `BigInteger` but fails because of `"14.399999999999999"` given.

So I suspect that `*.docx` file was not created using `Word` but using some other application or programmatically. And this other application or program had made that error.